# macOS Sierra GM seed - How to get to the final version from there?

Tags: macos

So, I know that the GM seed of macOS Sierra is identical to the release version which will come later this month.

If I'd install this GM seed now, how do I get to the release version? Or does it recognize that it's practically the release version?

Or do I really have to install an old non-beta backup in order to get the release version?

Comment: Usually the GM Seed and the final public release are the same built number

Comment: So that means if I installed it, it's the "normal" version, that everyone has?

Comment: Unless there's some major unforseen bug between these timings which is very unlikely; and you'll be and to clarify that by then comparing the build numbers

Comment: I would have upvoted or accepted an answer, but I can't :D Thank you